# How To Create Tabs in Javascript with Hide, Disable and Enable Function

Tags: javascript, tabs

I want to create Javascript Tabs From Scratch

- Tab links need to be responsive.
- Tab links should also change the orientation or the alignment from Horizontal to vertical
- Tab Should include  one form in multiple tab links, so that form can submitted in last tab.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is 4 Steps to create Javascript Tabs from scratch
  
Copy following Css, Javascript , HTML and Finally Initialize Tabs in Script



**Step 1: Copy the following Css For Tabs**

:root {
/*Color Used*/

--CrTe: rgb(70 164 199/ 0.91); /*ColorTheme */
--CrTeRGB: 70 164 199; /*ColorThemeRGB*/
--CrTeTtLt: white; /*ColorThemeLight*/
--CrTeHrTt: white; /*ColorThemeHoverText*/

--CrTeBr: rgb(var(--CrTeRGB)/.95); /*ColorThemeBorder*/

/*Red Green Yellow Black Brown Grey Orange Blue Pink Voilet White*/
--CrRd: 255 0 0;
--CrGn: 21 173 145;
--CrYw: 238 225 26;
--CrBk: 23 22 22;
--CrBn: 98 53 3;
--CrGy: 108 103 103;
--CrOe: 236 134 9;
--CrBe: 70 164 199;
--CrPk: 222 203 223;
--CrVt: 151 9 248;
--CrWe: 239 239 239;
--CrTeBdBody: rgb(245 246 246 / 0.95); /*ColorThemeBackground */

}

/*Pixel Equivalent rem*/
--Pl0: 0rem;
--Pl1: 0.0625rem;
--Pl2: 0.125rem;
--Pl3: 0.1875rem;
--Pl4: 0.25rem;
--Pl5: 0.3125rem;
--Pl6: 0.375rem;
--Pl7: 0.4375rem;
--Pl8: 0.5rem;
--Pl9: 0.5625rem;
--Pl10: 0.625rem;
--Pl30: 1.875rem;
/*Rem Ends*/

.CrBdWe85{background-color:rgb(var(--CrWe)/.85) !important;}

/*Padding*/
.Pg7{padding:var(--Pl7) !important;}
.Pg3{padding:var(--Pl3) !important;}
.Pg10{padding:var(--Pl10) !important;}
.PgLtRt10{padding-left: var(--Pl10) !important;padding-right: var(--Pl10) !important;}

.BrRs15{border-radius:var(--Pl15) !important;}

/*Tabs Css*/
.UTabLink {
    padding: var(--Pl8) var(--Pl5);
    cursor: pointer;
    min-height: var(--Pl30);
    display: flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
    font-weight: 500;
    border-right: var(--Pl1) solid rgb(236 236 236 / 0.95);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px var(--Pl6) rgb(236 236 236 / 0.95);
    margin: var(--Pl0) var(--Pl3) var(--Pl0) var(--Pl0);
    background-color: rgb( var(--CrTeRGB) /.15);
    transition: all ease-in-out .5s;
    transition-property: background-color,box-shadow;
    border-top-left-radius: var(--Pl3);
    border-top-right-radius: var(--Pl3);
    font-weight: 600;
}

.UTabActive, .UTabLink:hover {
        background-color: rgb( var(--CrTeRGB) /.8) !important;
        border-top: var(--Pl2) solid var(--CrTeBr) !important;
        color: var(--CrTeHrTt);
}

.UTabDeactive {
    background-color: rgb( var(--CrGy) / .4) !important;
    color: rgb(var(--CrWe)) !important;
    border-top: rgb(var(--CrGy)) !important;
    cursor: no-drop !important;
}

.UTabs {
    box-shadow: inset var(--Pl0) var(--Pl0) var(--Pl6) rgb(236 236 236 / 0.95);
    border-left: var(--Pl1) solid rgb(199 193 193 / 0.80);
    border-right: var(--Pl1) solid rgb(199 193 193 / 0.80);
    border-top: var(--Pl1) solid rgb(199 193 193 / 0.80);
    border-radius: var(--Pl2) var(--Pl2) var(--Pl0) var(--Pl0);
    box-shadow: var(--Pl0) var(--Pl2) var(--Pl2) rgb(199 193 193 / 0.80);
    padding: var(--Pl3) var(--Pl3) var(--Pl0) var(--Pl3);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    background-color: var(--CrTeBdBody);
}

.UTabsCont {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100px;
    padding: var(--Pl5);
    display: block;
    border-radius: var(--Pl0) var(--Pl0) var(--Pl2) var(--Pl2);
    border-left: var(--Pl1) solid rgb(199 193 193 / 0.80);
    border-right: var(--Pl1) solid rgb(199 193 193 / 0.80);
    border-bottom: var(--Pl1) solid rgb(199 193 193 / 0.80);
}

.UTabsContent > div:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
}
/*Tabs Css Ends*/

/*ShadowBoxInset1Div-Version1*/
.SwBxIt1Dv-Vn1 {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 var(--Pl6) var(--CrSwIr)
}
.SwBx1Dv-Vn1 {
    box-shadow: var(--Pl2) var(--Pl2) var(--Pl6) var(--Pl2) var(--CrSwOt);
}

.FxRw {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    width:100%;
}

.FxAnImSh {align-items: stretch;}

.Fx5, .Fx10, .Fx15, .Fx20, .Fx25, .Fx30, .Fx33, .Fx35, .Fx40, .Fx45, .Fx50,
.Fx55, .Fx60, .Fx65, .Fx70, .Fx75, .Fx80, .Fx85, .Fx90, .Fx95, .Fx100 {
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}

@@media (min-width: 768px) {
.Fx5{ flex: 0 0 5% ; max-width:5% ;}
.Fx10{ flex: 0 0 10% ; max-width:10% ;}
.Fx15{ flex: 0 0 15% ; max-width:15% ;}
.Fx20{ flex: 0 0 20% ; max-width:20% ;}
.Fx25{ flex: 0 0 25% ; max-width:25% ;}
.Fx30{ flex: 0 0 30% ; max-width:30% ;}
.Fx33{ flex: 0 0 33.333% ; max-width:33.333% ;}
.Fx35{ flex: 0 0 35% ; max-width:35% ;}
.Fx40{ flex: 0 0 40% ; max-width:40% ;}
.Fx45{ flex: 0 0 45% ; max-width:45% ;}
.Fx50{ flex: 0 0 50% ; max-width:50% ;}
.Fx55{ flex: 0 0 55% ; max-width:55% ;}
.Fx60{ flex: 0 0 60% ; max-width:60% ;}
.Fx65{ flex: 0 0 65% ; max-width:65% ;}
.Fx70{ flex: 0 0 70% ; max-width:70% ;}
.Fx75{ flex: 0 0 75% ; max-width:75% ;}
.Fx80{ flex: 0 0 80% ; max-width:80% ;}
.Fx85{ flex: 0 0 85% ; max-width:85% ;}
.Fx90{ flex: 0 0 90% ; max-width:90% ;}
.Fx95{ flex: 0 0 95% ; max-width:95% ;}
.Fx100{ flex: 0 0 100% ; max-width:100% ;}
}

/*Border-- -Cr implies to add class cr to show border*/
.Br1_Cr {
    border: var(--Pl1) solid !important;
}
.BrTp3_Cr{border-top:var(--Pl3) solid  !important;}

/*Border Color*/
.CrBrTe{border-color:var(--CrTeBr) !important;}

.BrRs5{border-radius:var(--Pl5) !important;}

/*Margin*/
.MnTp7{margin-top:var(--Pl7) !important;}
.MnBm7{margin-bottom:var(--Pl7) !important;}

.FxGw1 {flex-grow: 1;}

/*Btn Design*/
.BnRd15 {
    padding: var(--Pl5) var(--Pl7);
    font-size: var(--Pl15);
    font-weight: 400;
    border-radius: var(--Pl22);
    padding: var(--Pl4) var(--Pl9);
    border-color: transparent;
    border-width: var(--Pl2);
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    outline: none;
    transform: scale(.94);
}

/*ColorBackground*/
.CrBdTeBnNt {background-color:var(--CrTeBnNt ) !important;}

/*HoverTransformScale*/
.HrTmSeo94:hover {transform: scale(.94);transition: transform ease-in-out .4s;}
    /*Tabs Css Ends*/


**// Step2 Now Copy Add Following Script**
//Tabs Script
function TabsUT(TabLinkIdStg, TabActiveInt, TabDisableAryInt, TabHideAryInt) {
    var TablinkId = document.getElementById(TabLinkIdStg);
    TablinkId.classList.add("UTabs");
    var tablink = TablinkId.children;
    var tabcontent = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < tablink.length; i++) {
        //Adds TabContent
        var getContentTab = document.getElementById(TabLinkIdStg + "Cont" + i);
        tabcontent.push(getContentTab);
        //   
        //Adds Id To Link 
        tablink[i].setAttribute("id", TabLinkIdStg + [i]);
        tablink[i].setAttribute("Num", [i]);
        tablink[i].setAttribute('onclick', "ClickTabUT('" + TabLinkIdStg + "','" + TabLinkIdStg + [i] + "')");
        //Ends
        //Check Which Tab To be Activate At Start
        tablink[i].classList.add('UTabLink');
        tabcontent[i].classList.add('UTabCont');
        //Hide All TabContent First
        tabcontent[i].style.display = 'none'
        if (i === 0) {
            tablink[i].classList.add('UTabActive');
            tabcontent[i].style.display = 'block'
        }    
        if (TabActiveInt === i) {
            tablink[0].classList.remove('UTabActive');
            tablink[i].classList.add('UTabActive');
            tabcontent[0].style.display = 'none';
            tabcontent[i].style.display = 'block';
        }    
        //Ends
    }    
    try {    
        DisableTabUt(TabLinkIdStg, TabDisableAryInt);
    } catch { }
    try {    
        HideTabUt(TabLinkIdStg, TabHideAryInt)
    } catch { }
}    
function ClickTabUT(TabLinkIdStg, ClickedTabIdStg)
{    
    var tablink = document.getElementById(TabLinkIdStg).children;
    var tabcontent = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < tablink.length; i++)
    {    
        //Adds TabContent
        var getContentTab = document.getElementById(TabLinkIdStg + "Cont" + i);
        tabcontent.push(getContentTab);
    }    
    for (var i = 0; i < tablink.length; i++) {
        try { tabcontent[i].style.display = 'none'; }
        catch { }
        try {    
            tablink[i].classList.remove("UTabActive");
        }    
        catch { }
    }    
    var clickedtab = document.getElementById(ClickedTabIdStg);
    clickedtab.classList.add("UTabActive");
    tabcontent[clickedtab.getAttribute("Num")].style.display = "block";
}    
function DisableTabUt(TabLinkIdStg, TabDisableInt)
{    
    for (var i = 0; i < TabDisableInt.length; i++)
    {    
        var tabId = TabLinkIdStg + TabDisableInt[i];
        var tab = document.getElementById(tabId) ;
        tab.removeAttribute("onclick");
        document.getElementById(TabLinkIdStg + "Cont" + TabDisableInt[i]).style.display = "none";
        if (tab.classList.contains("UTabActive"))
        {    
            tab.classList.remove('UTabActive');
        }    
            tab.classList.add('UTabDeactive');
    }    
}    
function HideTabUt(TabLinkIdStg, TabHideAryInt)
{    
    for (var i = 0; i < TabHideAryInt.length; i++)
    {    
        var tabId = TabLinkIdStg + TabHideAryInt[i];
        var tab = document.getElementById(tabId);
        document.getElementById(TabLinkIdStg + "Cont" + TabHideAryInt[i]).style.display = "none";
        tab.style.display = "none";
        if (tab.classList.contains("UTabActive")) {
            tab.classList.remove('UTabActive');
        }    
    }    
}    
function ActiveTabUt(TabLinkIdStg, TabActiveInt) {
    var TablinkId = document.getElementById(TabLinkIdStg);
    TablinkId.classList.add("UTabs");
    var tablink = TablinkId.children;
    tablink[TabActiveInt].setAttribute('onclick', "ClickTabUT('" + TabLinkIdStg + "','" + TabLinkIdStg + [TabActiveInt] + "')");
    var tabcontent = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < tablink.length; i++) {
        //Adds TabContent
        var getContentTab = document.getElementById(TabLinkIdStg + "Cont" + i);
        tabcontent.push(getContentTab);
        //Hide All TabContent First
        tabcontent[i].style.display = 'none'
        if (tablink[i].classList.contains('UTabActive')) {
            tablink[i].classList.remove('UTabActive');
        }    
        if (TabActiveInt === i) {
            if (tablink[i].classList.contains('UTabDeactive'))
            {    
                tablink[i].classList.remove('UTabDeactive');
            }    
            tablink[i].classList.add('UTabActive');
            tablink[i].style.display = 'flex';
            tabcontent[i].style.display = 'block';
        }    
    }    
}    
//Ends

**//Step3 Finally Here the Html Part.**
```

***Note: Tab Content Id Should Be Have Suffix Of TabLink Div Id eg. id="UTabs9" is TablinkIdand Tab Content id's are id="UTabs9Cont0" , id="UTabs9Cont1" as many as tablinks.***

```
<div class="SwBx1Dv-Vn1 CrBdWe85 Pg7 BrRs15">
    <div class="FxRw FxAnImSh">
        <div class="Fx100 Pg3">
            <div id="UTabs9">
                <div>Detail</div>
                <div>Other Detail</div>
                <div><i class="UT-ImageLine"></i></div>
            </div>

            <div class="BrTp3_Cr Br1_Cr CrBrTe BrRs5 ">

                    <div id="UTabs9Cont0">
                        <div class="Pg10">
                           Tab1
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="UTabs9Cont1">
                        <div class="Pg10">
                            Tab2
                        </div>
                    </div>

                <div id="UTabs9Cont2">
                    <div class="Pg12">
                           Demo of the Tab Tab 3
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

**//Step4 Finally Intialize Tabs on page load.**
 TabsUT('UTabs9', 0, [], []);
```